# Как удалить DOM элемент React и заново отрисовать?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

у меня вопрос про удаление элемента и его отрисовку. Дело в том, что я пытаюсь сделать код, который если нажать на один элемент, то он бы удалял DOM элемент и заново бы рендерило бы. Но у меня вылетает ошибка: `Warning: unmountComponentAtNode(): The node you're attempting to unmount was rendered by React and is not a top-level container. You may have accidentally passed in a React root node instead of its container.`. Лично я не знаю как решить эту проблему. Простите за такой вопрос - я можно сказать новичок в react и работал (да и сейчас работаю) с Node js и Electron js.

```
let session = {
      login: '890yhj',
      password: 'oiwcfsmn'
}
const content = $('#content')[0];

    function newSess(){
    class NewUser extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.newRender = this.newRender.bind(this);
    }
    newRender(){
      session.login = document.getElementById('log').value;
        session.password = document.getElementById('passwort').value;
        let remEl =  document.getElementById('avtroizer');
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(remEl);
        newSess();
    }
    render() {
      return(
        <div id="avtroizer">
          <div id="avtrizerBox">
            <div className="boxAvtor">
              <h3>Вход для ученика</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="boxAvtor">
              <p><label>Логин</label></p>
              <p><input type="text" id="log" placeholder="Введите логин"></input></p>
            </div>
            <div className="boxAvtor">
              <p><label>Пароль</label></p>
              <p><input type="text" id="passwort"placeholder="Введите пароль"></input></p>
            </div>
            <div className="boxAvtor">
              <p><label onClick={this.newRender}>Вход</label></p>
            </div>
            <div className="boxAvtor">
              <a href="./admin">Вход для учителя</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
newSess();
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: В react не допускается прямая манипуляция с ДОМ елементами, это антипаттерн. Используей state и условный рендеринг. https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: React  нужно представлять, как отражение. Отразить елемент неко  - зеркально. Человек выше верно сказал, вы меняете состояние, перендриваются компоненты, если active = false, .  Тогда отразить как  null. В случае  null  компонент не будет зарендрин.

Comment: Допустим есть компонент  basket и некое состояние, которое isBasket, вы пишите  isBasket ? <Basket\> : null  Когда  isBasket   true,  вы видите компонент, если он становится false,  рендрится null,  в  react  это аналог удаления элементов.